# Along what curve does an ellipse roll down the fastest?

Tags: reference-request, mp.mathematical-physics

For the original Brachistochrone problem, Johan Bernoulli proved that it is the cycloid curve along which a circle* rolls down (without friction) the fastest under the influence of a uniform gravitational field. Since then, numerous generalizations of the problem have been posed and solved, see for instance this [paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/24340713) by Gemmer.

I wonder whether a particular generalization of this problem has also been considered - one in which it is not a circular bead that rolls down the curve, but a ellipse-shaped one. Like this (here, it rolls down a paroboloid curve):

$\hskip2in$  [image]

Among the many generalizations considered in the paper mentioned above, I could not find this one.

**Question**: has an ellipsoid version of the Brachistochrone problem been considered yet, and has a solution in terms of the appropriate curve been found already?

(*) *Note*: as pointed out by Manfred Weis in the comments, Bernoulli's solution involved finding the curve of fastest descent of a *point*, not a circle. In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4416281/along-what-curve-does-a-circle-roll-down-the-fastest) MSE question, I ask about the curve of fastest descent for a circle with radius $r$.

Comment: An ellipse rolls really weirdly, right? I think if it starts slow, there are many combinations of initial orientation and slope where it just doesn't roll further downhill (as long as we impose infinite friction to disallow sliding, of course). And if it picks up enough speed, I believe it can jump off the curve. So some additional thought seems required to even pose the problem.

Comment: @AchimKrause Good points. I think one should restrict the set of possible curves to the ones that do not allow the ellipse to jump off

Comment: I think for a given non-circle ellipse, there is always a threshold speed $v$ such that it cannot roll along even a flat horizontal line with speed exceeding $v$ without jumping. So beyond a certain starting height, I wouldn't even be sure whether there exists any curve such that the given ellipse can roll down from the given height without jumping at some point.

Comment: @AchimKrause Perhaps that's an interesting problem by itself: find a curve along which an ellipse does not jump when it rolls down - or prove such curves do not exist

Comment: What motivates this question? Eg the circular version is close to the big 18th-century question of how to keep time well: if a pendulum is constrained so that the end travels in an appropriate cycloid, then each pass takes the same amount of time regardless of how high it starts. Are there any engineering problems well modeled by rolling ellipses?

Comment: @MattF. Rolling ellipses doesn't model any engineering problems that I know of (I'm not an engineer though, my knowledge on that topic is limited). This question is mainly motivated by curiosity. I was also quite surprised by the idea that generalizations of the Brachistochrone problem don't seem to have formulated often in the direction of considering objects of different shapes rolling from curves - besides circles and cylinders. The ellipse seemed like a good starting point because of its similarities to a circle

Comment: The circle has the great virtue of rotational symmetry, so that it's clear what is meant by rolling from A to B. For any other shape, I think you need to define the problem in more detail. From centre of mass at A and rotation $\theta$ in some natural basis to centre of mass at B and arbitrary rotation?

Comment: I wonder if the solution will undulate, like how a square-wheeled bicycle can travel on inverted catenaries.

Comment: Did Bernoully really consider a rolling circle? According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brachistochrone_curve) it was a **point** on which gravity acts. Therefore IMO the ideal curve for an ellipse would render its center of mass trace out the brachistochrone

Comment: @ManfredWeis you're right, it was indeed a point. I stand corrected

Comment: @ManfredWeis do you know of a source where a version of this problem is solved with a circular-shaped object rolling down a curve?

Comment: @MaxMuller I'm not aware of such a source but my educated guess would be that a good approximation to the solution is the [Parallel curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_curve) that has distance $r$ to the "outside" of the cycloid curve that resembles the circle-center's Brachistochrone

Comment: Here's a source that seems to agree with the guess of @ManfredWeis: L.D. Akulenko, [The brachistochrone problem for a disc](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jappmathmech.2009.08.0150), Journal of Applied Mathematics and Mechanics, Volume 73, Issue 4.

Comment: Fastest means optimization. This is a problem of Calculus of Variations. Is it allowed the curve to have changing signs curvatures (undulate)?. I mean, to be different what is drawn?

Comment: @JorgeZuniga Yes, it is allowed to undulate

Comment: @Timothy, a working doi to Akulenko's paper seems to be https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jappmathmech.2009.08.015

Comment: @WillieWong In the following video, it is shown how an ellipse can roll along a sine wave: https://youtu.be/Y0aOxj5lrKY

Comment: @AchimKrause You may find the above video interesting, too. It provides an example of a curve along which the ellipse doesn't jump

Comment: Interesting! It seems to me that if we tilt that curve, the ellipse would actually roll down arbitrarily far, without jumping, since its center of gravity moves along a straight line. If the center of gravity's path exhibits any downwards curvature, then once the velocity of the ellipse is fast enough, the required acceleration to keep it on its path exceeds gravity, and it jumps off. So it seems that any curve without jumping has to "asymptotically agree" with the curve in the video, whatever that precisely means.

Answer (score 2):

Let the ellipse have major axes of lengths $a\ge b\gt 0$.

"Enclose" the ellipse in a disk $D$ of with radius $r=a$ and let it roll without slip on the curve $B^+$ parallel at distance $a$ to the Brachistochrone of $D$'s center; this yields a set  of ellipses with major axes lengths $a$ and $b$ centered on the Brachistochrone and rotated by an angle $\varphi$.

Take as an at least approximate solution for the sought curve the "outer" envelope curve of the set of ellipses generated by the rolling disk that encloses the ellipse.

The idea carries over to other shapes taking as the enclosing disk the smallest on that is centered at the candidate shape's center of mass and proceed as in case of the ellipse; it should be noted that using the smallest enclosing circle is not correct because the center of mass shall be confined to a Brachistochrone.

Comment: That's an original and creative solution. The spirit of this question was more along the lines of letting the ellipse roll down the slope by itself though, without enclosing it by other shapes

Comment: @MaxMuller the ellipse will roll down fastest by itself on the mentioned envelope curve whose construction is explained via enclosing the ellipse in a disk; I see that I will eventually have provide a visualization or precise mathematical defintion.

Comment: Ah okay yes, maybe I don't fully understand what you mean by "closure" in this sense. A visualization would be awesome! And it would be interesting to understand why this type of rolling descent of the ellipse doesn't result in jumps (see the points of Achim Krause)